# Comprabar si esta vacia o no una lista

Tags: c#

Cuando doy de alta una solicitud y añado "equipos" a dicha solicitud, me genera una lista de los equipos que tengo del dicho cliente que selecciono anteriormente...

Como puedo comprobar si en dicha lista esta vacia o no

```
string Equipos = string.Empty;
List<string> EquiposNombre = new List<string>();
bool isEmpty = isEmpty(EquiposNombre);
if (isEmpty)
{
  foreach (var ar in solicitud.ActivosReportados)
  {                      
    EquiposNombre.Add(Utilidades.ActivoNombrePorActivoTipoIdActivoId(ar.ActivoId, 
     ar.ActivoTipoId));
  }
  Equipos = string.Join(", ", EquiposNombre);
}
```

Tengo una variable boleana para comprobar si esta vacia pero no me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber si una lista es vacía puedes hacer la siguiente condición:

```
 EquiposNombre.Count==0;
```

Si el número de elementos es igual a 0 significa que está vacía.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho

Answer (score 1):

Exite un metodo en linq que verifica si una lista o cualquier instancia que derive de IEnumerable esta lleno o no. Por ejemplo:

```
var lista = new List<string>();
if (lista.Any())
{
   //En caso este lleno
}
```

Espero te ayude ¡Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, ahora se otra manera de hacerlo :)